# Pathogen does not load plugins for Mac

Tags: macos, vim

I'm using same dotfiles for vim in mac and windows. They works fine with windows, But does not work in Mac.

**.vimrc**

```
call pathogen#infect()    " Reload all plugins
call pathogen#helptags()  " Generate helptags for everything in 'runtimepath'

set nocompatible          " Remove backwards compatibility with old Unix systems. This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.


" --------------------------------- NERDTree -----------------------------------

"Open NERDTree automatically when vim start up if no files were specified
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif

map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR> "To open NERDTree with Ctrl+n

"Close vim if only window left open is a NERDTree
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTreeType") && b:NERDTreeType == "primary") | q | endif

" ---------------------------------- CtrlP -------------------------------------

" Change the default mapping and the default command to invoke CtrlP
let g:ctrlp_map = '<c-p>'
let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlP'

let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'ra'                  " Unless a starting directory specified, CtrlP will set its local working directorPathogen does not load pluginsy

" Use a custom file listing command
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'find %s -type f'          " MacOSX/Linux
" let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'dir %s /-n /b /s /a-d'  " Windows
```

**ls -A ~/.vim/bundle**

```
ctrlp.vim   nerdtree
```

**:scriptnames**

```
  1: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimrc
  2: ~/.vimrc
  3: ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
  4: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/filetype.vim
  5: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/menu.vim
  6: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/autoload/paste.vim
  7: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/indent.vim
  8: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
  9: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/synload.vim
 10: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
 11: ~/.vim/colors/solarized.vim
 12: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftoff.vim
 13: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin.vim
 14: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 15: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim
 16: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/logiPat.vim
 17: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/manpager.vim
 18: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/matchparen.vim
 19: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 21: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/spellfile.vim
 22: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 23: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/tohtml.vim
 24: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 25: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 26: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/gvimrc
 27: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/scripts.vim
 28: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/indent/vim.vim
 29: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/vim.vim
 30: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/perl.vim
 31: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/pod.vim
 32: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/ruby.vim
 33: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/python.vim
 34: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-104/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin/vim.vim
```

Comment: As your comment shown above, and the help for `nocompatible` both say, if you use it, it should be at the very top before anything else. Did you try that?

Comment: Also you have not stated what isn't working. Do the plugins just not load? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: @DanLowe Yep, It's not work for me, i'm getting error message

"Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
E492: Not an editor command:  NERDTree | endif"

Comment: I tried your vim setup on my Mac and it works as expected (nerdtree opens if I just type "vim", and doesn't if I edit a certain file). Could not reproduce. Perhaps you should make sure you get a fresh copy of nerdtree, make sure there is nothing wrong with the nerdtree module under bundle directory?